# accessing localhost from vm

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need to access my local environment from inside a vm. There's several posts about how to do this, but I need to be able to access my localhost by typing "localhost" in the address bar, because it uses facebook authentification, and if the domain is not recognized, it doesn't work.

How can I set so that "localhost" in my vm points to "localhost" outside the vm ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can change the IP address of the localhost to whatever the IP of the host has in your hosts file.

If the vm machine is windows the file is located at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

just open up the hosts file in notepad and edit

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
192.168.0.1 localhost
```

not sure if it works, but you can atleast try

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel stupid not to have thought of that by myself. FTR, VirtualBox use 10.0.2.2 to access the host.

Comment: This worked for me after hours of trying other shit, thank you